# Type for large currency values in C++

Tags: c++, currency

What type should i use in C++ to store large currecy values like 5231451.3245114414? It should allow to store 10 or even more decimal digits.

Comment: If you want that much precision, I would venture that "currency" is an irrelevant detail here.

Comment: @Oli not necessarily. Currencies sometimes have the requirement of exact representation, which means that binary fractions (= `float`, `double`) aren’t viable.

Comment: @Oli: Nonsense! I was in the newsagents yesterday and the racist cashier charged me £5.00000000001!

Comment: @Konrad: Currencies should _always_ be represented by integers. Usually pennies, or tenths of pennies or so, though some applications may require more precision (e.g. banking). 10dp just seems silly though.

Comment: Integer pennies? BitCoin, anyone?

Comment: Currency is usually stored to max 2 or 4 decimals, otherwise rounding errors crop up. You need to mimic a Decimal or Currency type.

Comment: @Konrad: I think Oli is referring to the fact that monetary amounts usually don't have all those decimal places.

Comment: @clumpter: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Tomalak: presuming they'd have charged someone of different race a fiver, that's only a *very slightly* racist cashier :-)

Comment: @Steve: the problem is that the cashier insisted for him to pay *exactly* that amount, and Tomalak didn't have a 0.00000000001 £ coin at hand. :(

Comment: @Tomalak “Currencies should always be represented by integers” – that’s what I used to think, too, but I’ve recently been told (here on SO, no less, and by a presumed expert, though I’ve forgotten who that was) that in fact most banking business uses binary floating point arithmetic. Presumably the minuscule differences even out in the long run, and using cheaper CPU operations presumably pays in lower power bills.

Comment: @Konrad: having seen several security WTFs on remote banking websites I wouldn't accept everything banking business do as "best practice". :S

Comment: @Konrad: Did you hear about something called the "global financial crisis"?

Comment: @Tomalak: so you are telling me that the subprime mortages are a hoax and everything comes from accumulated rounding errors? `:o` ... well, it still sounds more credible...

Comment: @Matteo: No, I'm just saying -- as did you -- that banking practices are hardly the pinnacle of awesomeness.

Comment: @Matteo Presumably, that’s different. Surprisingly, security holes haven’t incurred a big enough cost in the past for banks to fix them. Or rather, it was cheaper to tolerate the occasional (~ several thousand times a day) theft than to fix the system. Why pay a security expert when you can pay the insurance (less) instead?

Comment: @Tomalak: sure, I was just jocking :)

Comment: @Konrad: it makes sense, although from an engineering standpoint it's still an abomination.

Comment: Binary fraction representations could be OK, provided the values you actually care about (at 0.1 intervals up to a certain value) are sufficiently far apart that you can round back to 0.1 whenever you like, and errors don't accumulate faster than you round back. Then you'll get the same results as a decimal representation. Of course testing/proving that this is the case is fiddly. I speculate that even if you round back on every single operation, it can still be faster than a custom base-10 class doing everything in software. Same results faster, isn't an abomination. Lack of testing would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all for your answers. I found the most appropriate solution myself. It's just one file that does everything i need - [C++ wrapper class for the OLE Automation type DECIMAL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/decimalwrap.aspx). It's really light (no additional heavy libraries or files) and powerfull and can handle REALLY BIG numbers.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how large your values are, and more importantly on the required precision.

If all numbers have the same precision and scale, say 10 places after the decimal point and no bigger than one million, then you could just use long integers (multiply everything by 10<sup>10</sup>, etc.).

If you truly need arbitrary scales and precision, you won't get around an arbitrary-precision library. A quick search turned up [mpdecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html), but there may be others. Combining the fixed-point approach with arbitrary precision, you could also just use libgmp for arbitrary-precision integers but treat them all as units of 10<sup>10</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a custom type that mimics what Java's BigDecimal does.

A 64-bit double precision number is only accurate to 17 digits, so you'll have to do better than that.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. You're just saying "you're going to have to look somewhere else".

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check if [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) suits what you need.  It got a C++ wrapper if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with monetary values you probably want a fixed-point decimal class, so something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fp_math.aspx) should do the trick.

Since you want all that precision (out of curiosity: why do you need that for monetary amounts?) you should probably use a 64 bit integer as its base type (it should be enough for up to ~18 total decimal digits). If that still isn't enough you'll have to use some biginteger library to have an arbitrarily-big integer as the base for the fixed point decimal class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at decNumber++? Link can be found at http://speleotrove.com/decimal/ ?